# Can't NgFor in a array

Tags: angular

I'm getting this error while retrieving the array of users:
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

The request function on the service:

```
getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:3000/users')
  .pipe(map((res: any) => {
    return res;
  }))
  }
```

The html component:

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of userData">
      <td>{{user.id}}</td>
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td>{{user.email}}</td>
      <td>{{user.password}}</td>
```

The TS component:

```
  getAllUsers(){
    this.accountService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(res=>{
      console.log('getallusers novo',res);
      this.userData = res;
    },
    err=>{
      console.log(err);
      alert('faio');
    })
  }
```

I want to fetch the users from the URL, when I do the request on Postman it's OK.
[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gbx1.png)

Comment: Well, the `map` has no effect so you can remove it. Anyway, what's exactly the problem you're facing?

Comment: show us the result of the postman

Comment: You should retutn `res.users` not the `res` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this  :

```
getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.http.get<any[]>('http://localhost:3000/users')
  .pipe(map((res: any) => {
    return res.users;
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error [object Object] say that you try to do a loop with a OBJECT.

You need converter this OBJECT in ARRAY.

You can do three options:

1. In the api, answer with a ARRAY
2. In the frontend, execute this processes a convert the OBJECT in ARRAY:

https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/convert-an-object-to-an-array-in-javascript/

3. Do this in getAllUsers():

this.userData = res.users;

(res.users is a ARRAY)